# Excel code to update Powerpoint presentation links. File opens as read only

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Using Excel to updates the links in this file. When it opens it opens as Read Only.

```
Set pApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pApp.Visible = True

pApp.Presentations.Open Filename:="https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Boards/safety/Shared_ 
Documents/123/safety123 Assembly.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoFalse

pApp.ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
ActivePresentation.Save
ActivePresentation.Close
```

Comment: That's to be expected when you open a presentation from a web server. Instead, open it from a network file share.

Comment: Is there a way around this? I have several presentations that we need to update the links that are located on this Sharepoint cloud site.

Comment: You'll have to download the files, run the VBA, then upload them again. VBA was written before the internet and depends on a local file system to operate. To work programmatically with online files, Office.js is a much better bet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office

Comment: @JohnKorchok A little different take on this:  I think this might be more an MS security thing than a VBA vs The Internet problem. You can open files from the web, insert pictures from the web etc, but security restrictions introduced much after VBA will, for example, make files you download from the net open in read-only mode until you've unblocked them in File Explorer. Tedious.   

Discuss.  ;-)